# Where is Wordpress direct download link?

Tags: wordpress, download, wget

Wordpress not using direct linking for the download links (looks like enterprise software developer who generate links dynamically to track installation).

Use `wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz` is not getting the right file name.

I dont want save in desktop and upload to server because I'm running slow internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see what the problem is:

```
marc@panic:~$ wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
--2011-04-01 11:19:27--  http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
Resolving wordpress.org... 72.233.56.139, 72.233.56.138
Connecting to wordpress.org|72.233.56.139|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `latest.tar.gz'

    [          <=>                          ] 2,365,766   1.09M/s
```

Comment: It should be `wordpress-3.1.tar.gz` and not `latest.tar.gz`. I'm just feel bad about that

Comment: Then go off the links at http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/ if you want a specific version.